# When I call a function, should I assign the values that are returned in the functions to the variables outside the function, to get the updated value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say we have ***three variables***, `a`, `b` and `c`;

The variable '`a`' is assigned a ***boolean value*** of "`false`",
the variable '`b`' is assigned an integer number of `10` and
the variable '`c`' contains a list of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as an array.

After that, we have a function that ***modifies*** all of the values of the above ***three variables*** as follows:

**#1)** This is the Function that modifies the values declared outside the function.

```
function modifyAllValues(a, b, c){
    a = true;
    b = b + 10;
    c.pop();

    return [a, b, c];
}
```

**#2)** This is the MAIN Part of the Program where the variables are declared, and where the function will be called:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let a = false;
    let b = 10;
    let c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
});
```

My Question here is which one of the following is the right way to get the updated/modified values that are returned by `modifyAllValues` function, **A** or **B**?

**A)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*-----method 1-----*/

    let tempArray = modifyAllValues(a, b, c);
    /* Assigning the returned values back to the declared variables */
    a = tempArray[0];
    b = tempArray[1];
    c = tempArray[2];

    //console.log(a) => true
    //console.log(b) => 20
    //console.log(c) => [1, 2, 3, 4]
});
```

**B)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*-----method 2-----*/

    let tempArray = modifyAllValues(a, b, c);
    /* Using the values without assigning the returned values to variables */
    //console.log(a) => true
    //console.log(b) => 20
    //console.log(c) => [1, 2, 3, 4]
});
```

Thank You So Much!

Comment: Have you *tried* the two approaches?

Comment: Either way works, there is no 'best' as it entirely depends on your specific use case. That being said, I personally prefer declaring/using variables within local scope, so I would generally opt for the first approach. It's also worth noting that I wouldn't return an array for this. Use an object so the values can be assigned meaningful property names, rather than hoping no one ever messes within the indexes in the returned array.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm not sure how **B** could possibly work; the variables modified in the function are parameters, and the scalar ones will thus be copies of the variables in the calling environment.

Comment: @Pointy true - I was assuming in that snippet that `a`, `b`, and `c` are declared at some higher level (hopefully not global), although it's not shown. If that's not the case then the second example is moot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "*When a variable is declared inside a function, it is only accessible within that function and cannot be used outside that function.*" You must consider the scope. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, I have tried both approaches, and the first one looks like it's not responding...(the values are not updating as expected). In my Web Project, I was using the first approach, however the result wasn't as I expected..., So I changed my option to the second approach
@Pointy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  // Declaration of Variables
  var a = false;
  var b = 10;
  var c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  // Declaration of Function
  function modifyAllValues() {
    a = true;
    b = b + 10;
    c.pop();
  }

  // Event
  modifyAllValues();

  // Output
  console.log(a, b, c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As the variables were defined, outside the function, in a more global space, they can be modified by a function.

Now consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  // Declaration of Variables
  var x = false;
  var y = 10;
  var z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  // Declaration of Function
  function modifyAllValues(a, b, c) {
    a = true;
    b = b + 10;
    c.pop();

    return {
      "a": a,
      "b": b,
      "c": c
    };
  }

  // Event
  var results = modifyAllValues(x, y, z);
  x = results.a;
  y = results.b;
  z = results.c;

  // Output
  console.log(x, y, z);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This accepts parameters, modifies the, and returns them. `a`, `b`, and `c` are only defined within the scope of the function.